# Употребление с и со

Tags: предлоги

Перед словом "вшитым" следует употреблять предлог *с* или *со?*

Comment: 3 против 9 в пользу "с вшитым". Сайт: https://ruscorpora.ru/new/search-main.html
Запросы: "со вшит*" и "с вшит*"

Answer (score 2):

> Предлог со фонетически закономерен перед словами, начинающимися с
> сочетаний [с, з, ш, ж + согласная] или с согласной [щ]: со ста, со
> славой, со звездой, со шкафа, со жгутом, со щами. Поэтому: со зверем,
> но с зайцем.
>
> Также предлог со употребляется перед формами с начальными сочетаниями
> [л, ль, р, м] + согласная: со лба, со мной, со льдом, со ртом; также
> перед сочетаниями [в] + согласная: со вторника, со всеми, со второго. [Грамоту.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%20(%D1%81%D0%BE)&fbclid=IwAR1RuEaxGTAJb4diaFu4gRxQ_RJwCr7fco-0GE9gKTSmBu1rth2cXQcYdBs#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%20%D1%81%D0%BE%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4,%D1%81%D0%BE%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%81%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BC.)

Во «вшитым» первые две буквы не удовлетворяют шаблону [с, з, ш, ж + согласная], поэтому следует употреблять предлог «с»: «с вшитым».

Comment: А как же тогда быть с этим: "...также перед сочетаниями [в] + согласная..."?

Comment: НК РЯ фиксирует отношение «с вшитых» к «со вшитым» как пять к четырём.

Comment: Чем этот случай отличается от второй схемы из той же "грамоты" (в+согласная)?

Comment: Ну разница, наверное, есть. Во-первых, его выделили в ответе грамоты отдельно, не как фонетически закономерный случай, а просто как сложившийся случай. Во-вторых, разница видна по нацкорпусу. В-третьих, разница чувствуется по звучанию. Но посыл ответа, конечно, был не в том как надо писать, а в том, что можно как угодно. Если пошуршать по правилам, наверное и правило можно откопать соответствующее.

Comment: Всё-таки непонятно. *«…также перед сочетаниями [в] + согласная: со вторника, со всеми, со второго»* — по этому правилу должно быть «со вшитыми». В при поиске в Google: «с вшитыми» встречается 137 000 раз, а «со вшитыми» 79 400 раз. Таким образом «с вшитыми» используется в 1,7 раза, т. е. почти в 2 раза чаще. Должно же быть какое-то объяснение.

Comment: Такое происходит, когда правило придумывают "просто для порядка", чтобы унифицировать написание и потом потрясать этим правилом у всех перед носом. Что касается реального языка, то во всех таких случаях "из/изо; к/ко; о/об,..." одним из факторов выбора является письменность/устность речи. На письме удобнее короткие предлоги, а в произношении - длинные. Но это не единственный фактор. Еще есть дифференциация по падежам, на мой взгляд.